# jQuery / "selectIndex" issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

advise appreciated:

I have a drop-down list with "select..." at the top and then a list of links which, when clicked, each opens a different URL in a new window.

After user selection ("click") I however need that the drop-down always keeps showing "select..." and does NOT show what the user previously selected/clicked on.

I thought that this would do the job, but does not, it still shows whatever the user selected/clicked on in that drop-down, rather than always showing "select...".

Any suggestion how to fix greatly appreciated ! THANKS

```
var loadUrl= function(ctrl) { 
var booking  = jQuery(ctrl).children("option:selected");    
jQuery(ctrl).prop('selectedIndex',0);
var bookurl = jQuery(booking).attr("data-url");

var win=window.open(bookurl, '_blank');
win.focus();;
}
```

Comment: can you share the select also

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/faGBD/1/

Comment: hmmm, I see it working there, but I load the options from a JSON. maybe it has to do with the fact that the selection is in a JSON? This is the JSON file which has the links { "booking": [ {"key":"BOOKING_1","url":"google.com";}, {"key":"BOOKING_2", "url":"google.com";} ] }

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 jQuery("#ctrl").val(jQuery("#ctrloption:first").val());
```

or

```
 jQuery("#ctrl")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: no, none of them work, the first still shows the clicked on list entry and the second even prevents the click to open the link all together.

Comment: @user1402897:can you create the fiddle??

Comment: maybe it has to do with the fact that the selection is in a JSON?

This is the JSON file which has the links

{
    "booking": [
           
 {"key":"BOOKING_1","url":"http://google.com"},
 {"key":"BOOKING_2", "url":"http://google.com"}   
   
  ]
}